# Reason why I am having garbage values appear?

Tags: search, memory, mips, heap-memory, mars-simulator

So when I call this function for a value in my array, it prints out a garbage value then on the next line what I actually want to print. When I enter a value not in the array it errors out. I am new to this so could be something stupid

---

```
.data
array: .word 2,3,1,5,6,7,1,4,8,8    #elements
N: .word 10         # 10 elements
key: .word 0
int: .word 9

search:
   la      $a0, array         
   la      $t0, N
   lw      $t0, ($t0)
   sll     $t0, $t0, 2
   addi    $t0, $t0, -4
   add     $a1, $a0, $t0           
   la      $a0, array 
   jal     isort              #insert function from other function


li      $v0, 4                  
la      $a0, enterKey                # Display text
syscall 

li      $v0,5                    #  read input
syscall     
sw      $v0, key
syscall
move    $t0, $s0                 
lw $t1, N                       
lw      $t2, ($t0)               
li      $t3,0                    # $t3  i = 0
lw      $t4, int
lw      $t5, key
lw     $t6, int



loopKey:
beq     $t3, $t1, endKey         # if i = n, loop ends 
bne      $t2, $t5, condKey       # if the elements are not equal
move    $t4, $t3                 # assign index found to variable
j endKey

condKey:
addi    $t3, $t3, 1              # i++ 
addi    $t0, $t0, 4              
lw      $t2, ($t0)                
j       loopKey                    

endKey:                          
beq     $t4, $t6, noKey            #does not appear to even work???
li      $v0, 4                    
la      $a0, keyFmsg              
syscall
li      $v0, 1                    
add    $t4, $t4, 1              # have to add 1 for location not index
add     $a0, $zero, $t4      # prints the location
syscall
j     displayMenu              
noKey:                           #not working idk why
li      $v0, 4                   
la      $a0, keyNFmsg            
syscall
j     displayMenu
```

Comment: Why is there a `syscall` after `sw $v0, key`? As for your question, you've left out a bunch of code that's necessary for reproducing the issue. Use the debugging features in Mars to step to your program until you find where it goes wrong.